# Select files dialog does not appear for Firefox only when using Dropbox API mf_dropbox_id

Tags: firefox

I created a sample MVC application and included following code in it. Include it on any page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var mf_dropbox_width=480;
var mf_dropbox_id="03c14698019e70dede9ff2f115564f96af8f51dfd71439b44b03631f6cd44890";
</script><script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.mediafire.com/dropbox/dropbox.js">
</script>
```

The hyperlink select files does not work. Please click on the following link I found on web and when the page opens click select files. http://prewire-pics.blogspot.com/2011/11/var-mfdropboxwidth480var_6673.html The same works well in Internet Explorer and Chrome. Is there any security setting which I need to enable?

Comment: Doesn't work for me in Chrome on OS X, but I have Flash disabled. (It looks like this uses Flash.)

Comment: Cross-linking with https://www.dropboxforum.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/204288656-Select-files-dialog-does-not-appear-for-firefox-only-when-using-dropbox-api-mf-dropbox-id on the Dropbox API forum.

Comment: I'm removing the Dropbox tags as this actually appears to be related to MediaFire's FileDrop feature: http://knowledgebase.mediafire.com/article.php?id=142